# What's the difference between class and className with respect to css inheritance?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am exploring the css inheritance in react js.  I pass in the same object but I got two different results between using class and className.

Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/olk4xm60v6 (demo.js)

Comment: I think using `class` is invalid with react, nothing to do with CSS

Comment: @Pointy - the OP is referring to this statement in the React DOCS : _There are a number of attributes that work differently between React and HTML:_

Comment: @RandyCasburn my understanding is that React (maybe JSX generally) insists on `className`; I have no experience directly however.

Comment: The question should contain relevant code and be understandable without navigating to off-site link.

Answer (score 6):

In **ReactJs** you are writing **JSX** not **HTML** so you must follow the rules of jsx code

in **jsx** if you want to give class to certain tag you need to use `className` instead of *class*

Answer (score 3):

> To specify a CSS class, use the className attribute. This applies to
>   all regular DOM and SVG elements like `<div>`, `<a>`, and others.
>
> If you use React with Web Components (which is uncommon), use the
>   class attribute instead.

[**read doc**](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname)

[**Styling and CSS**](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)

Comment: Good start. Can you provide a little more explanation so the OP can understand what you mean by this terse response?